# Происхождение слова "жулик"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а слово "жулик" вообще русское? И имеет ли оно что-то общее с французским именем Жюль?
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Слово "жулик" русское. Оно есть в толковых словарях русского языка.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По Фасмеру: В русск. арго жулик имеет знач. "ученик преступника"; "маленький острый нож". Последнее знач., вероятно, является первичным, потому что жулить "резать" связано с болг. жуля "царапаю, тру, обдираю", сербохорв. жулити "драть", словен. јuґliti "усиленно тереть, жевать", наряду с сербохорв. гулити "драть";  русск. жуль "нож" (арго).

В других словарях (кроме значений, указанных выше) проводится параллель с "жилить", "жулить".

К имени Жюль отношение вряд ли имеет, тк Жюль, скорее всего, француский вариант имени Юлий

Answer (score 2):

По Шанскому: исконное, суф. производное  от жуль - вор, мошенник, в диалектах ещё отмечаемого, того же корня, что и  диал. жулить - присваивать чужое.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, корни этого слова намного более древние. И "острый нож", и "резать", и драть, царапать (этим же ножиком) можно рассматривать как вторичные.
Я нашла в русско-санскритском словаре слово *джулика* — мешочек, кошелёк. А т. к. санскрит древнее болгарского, сербохорватского, русского и прочих языков, можно предположить, что резали острым маленьким ножиком всё-таки кошельки — "джулики". Вот вам и жулики. Может быть, я не права, но очень уж очевидно.
Вообще в санскритском словаре я нашла такую массу слов, похожих на русский и не только, что просто полный восторг!

Comment: Интересная, нестандартная версия. Пожалуй, поддержу авансом. И добавлю для всех ссылку на слово *джулик*. (https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/visionary2007/post70001174)

Answer (score 0):

Нет ли связи со словом жульен? Французская этимология не выяснена. Однако жульен это способ нарезки в тонкую соломку. Жульеном также называют длинный острый нож, годный для такой нарезки. Мне кажется М.Фасмер с жуликом не ошибается. К примеру такой сюжет: Выскочил подлёт из подворотни, чиркнул жуликом по мошне и поминай как звали.

Comment: А жульен-то при чем? Да и насчет соломки - это значение узкопрофессионально и сомнительно само по себе как основание для русского слова. Я уж не говорю, что французское слово не могло так глубоко проникнуть в диалекты..